# Sort an array of std::pair vs. struct: which one is faster?

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, std-pair

I was wondering whether sorting an array of `std::pair` is faster, or an array of `struct`?

Here are my code segments:

**Code #1:** sorting `std::pair` array (by first element):

```
#include <algorithm>

pair <int,int> client[100000];

sort(client,client+100000);
```

**Code #2:** sort `struct` (by `A`):

```
#include <algorithm>

struct cl{
      int A,B;
}

bool cmp(cl x,cl y){
      return x.A < y.A;
}

cl clients[100000];

sort(clients,clients+100000,cmp);
```

**code #3:** sort `struct` (by `A` and internal operator `<`):

```
#include <algorithm>

struct cl{
      int A,B;

      bool operator<(cl x){
            return A < x.A;
      }
}

cl clients[100000];

sort(clients,clients+100000);
```

**Update:** I used these codes to solve a problem in an online Judge. I got *time limit* of 2 seconds for code #1, and *accept* for code #2 and #3 (ran in 62 milliseconds). Why code #1 takes so much time in comparison to other codes? Where is the difference?

Comment: The two approaches have different behaviour, so the question is moot.

Comment: Why can't you add a timestamp, run all solutions and simply compare the results? You already have a code, so it would only take minor modifications.

Comment: Why do you care about which one is faster ? Do you have a performance issue to solve ? Shouldn't you focus on your algorithms and data-structures **first** ?

Comment: First of all, you really should pass args not by value, but by const reference (`const cl& `)

Comment: Why do you want to compare the performance of code that does different things? This really makes no sense.

Comment: @ereOn: Not really... the code does not want any copies, so the version of the code which makes no copies whatsoever is probably preferable to the version which makes zero or one copy. (On the other hand, I would expect a pair of `int` to take up the same amount of memory as a reference, so the removed indirection may be helpful). The code is simple enough that we could expect the compiler to understand it either way, and to optimise it to the same thing.

Comment: @Mankarse: Indeed. But I already removed my comment a few minutes ago when I reread and realized MPogoda was talking about his specific code and not in general.

Comment: i solved a problem in an Online Judge with these two codes(pair sort , struct sort) . but my struct sort(code 2) get TL(Time limit)(2 seconds and more) and my pair sort(code 1) get AC(Accepted)(in 62 mili second). the codes was same except in way of sorting ???!!! and furthermore someones use code 3 and they get AC too! WHY? where is the difference?

Comment: You should at the very least pass by reference, instead of making copies in every call to `cmp` or your `operator<`. This could have an effect on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what `std::pair` is?  It's a struct (or class, which is the same thing in C++ for our purposes).  So if you want to know what's faster, the usual advice applies: you have to test it and find out for yourself on your platform.  But the best bet is that if you implement the equivalent sorting logic to `std::pair`, you will have equivalent performance, because the compiler does not care whether your data type's name is `std::pair` or something else.

But note that the code you posted is not equivalent in functionality to the `operator <` provided for `std::pair`.  Specifically, you only compare the first member, not both.  Obviously this may result in some speed gain (but probably not enough to notice in any real program).

Answer (score 1):

I would estimate that there isn't much difference at all between these two solutions.

But like ALL performance related queries, rather than rely on someone on the internet telling they are the same, or one is better than the other, make your own measurements. Sometimes, subtle differences in implementation will make a lot of difference to the actual results.

Having said that, the implementation of `std::pair` is a struct (or class) with two members, `first` and `second`, so I have a hard time imagining that there is any real difference here - you are just implementing your own pair with your own compare function that does exactly the same things that the already existing pair does... Whether it's in an internal function in the class or as an standalone function is unlikely to make much of a difference.

Edit: I made the following "mash the code together":

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int size=100000000;

pair <int,int> clients1[size];

struct cl1{
    int first,second;
};


cl1 clients2[size];

struct cl2{
      int first,second;

      bool operator<(const cl2 x) const {
            return first < x.first;
      }
};
cl2 clients3[size];




template<typename T>
void fill(T& t)
{
    srand(471117);   // Use same random number each time/ 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(t) / sizeof(t[0]); i++)
    {
    t[i].first = rand();
    t[i].second = -t[i].first;
    }
}



void func1()
{
    sort(clients1,clients1+size);
}


bool cmp(cl1 x, cl1 y){
      return x.first < y.first;
}

void func2()
{
    sort(clients2,clients2+size,cmp);
}


void func3()
{
    sort(clients3,clients3+size);
}

void benchmark(void (*f)(), const char *name)
{
    cout << "running " << name << endl;
    clock_t time = clock();
    f();
    time = clock() - time;
    cout << "Time taken = " << (double)time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}

#define bm(x) benchmark(x, #x)

int main()
{
    fill(clients1);
    fill(clients2);
    fill(clients3);

    bm(func1);
    bm(func2);
    bm(func3);
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
running func1
Time taken = 10.39
running func2
Time taken = 14.09
running func3
Time taken = 10.06
```

I ran the benchmark three times, and they are all within ~0.1s of the above results.

Edit2:
And looking at the code generated, it's quite clear that the "middle" function takes quite a bit longer, since the comparison is made inline for `pair` and `struct cl2`, but can't be made inline for `struct cl1` - so every compare literally makes a function call, rather than a few instructions inside the functions. This is a large overhead.

Comment: There is a difference. The `std::pair` example does something different to both `struct` examples.

Comment: @juanchopanza: why they are different? i solved a problem in an Online Judge with these two codes(pair sort , struct sort) . but my struct sort(code 2) get TL(Time limit)(2 seconds and more) and my pair sort(code 1) get AC(Accepted)(in 62 mili second). the codes was same except in way of sorting ???!!! and furthermore someones use code 3 and they get AC too!

Comment: Right, a `pair` compare will compare both halfs of the pair (if the `first` is equal). @today: If you already KNOW that there is a big difference, then perhaps you should rephrase your question to ask WHY there is a big difference?

Comment: @today the version using `std::pair` performs a lexicographical comparison involving the `first` and the `second` fields. Your `struct` versions only compare the first field. You would be guaranteed to get the same results only if you have unique first fields in your data.

Comment: @today: Is this using exactly this struct, or was your "online judge" using a different data structure than two integers? That would make a BIG difference if you for example have an object in there that has a complex constructor [`std::string` for example].

Comment: @MatsPetersson:at the first Thanks for benchmark; these are my two codes:                                   Pair sort : [link]http://paste.org/61770 (GET AC) time: 62 miliseconds                                                          Struct sort : [link]http://paste.org/61773 (GET TL) time : > 2 sec           Struct (v2) Sort : [link]http://paste.org/61775 (GET AC) time: same as pair sort

Comment: All I can say is that it's probably down to the inlining of the compare component. Although it would be running on a pretty slow machine if it takes 62 milliseconds. My machine, I had to multiply the size by 50 to make it take around 5 seconds, and the result above is from 100x the size in those examples.